# Laravel - not writing anything to new column in table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have added a new column to a table in my DB with migration. The column was created correctly. But when I am trying to write values to it, nothing gets written. This is my code:

```
if ($alternativeId > 0) {
            $answered = 'yes';
        }
        else {
            $answered = 'not';    
        }

        $answer = Answer::create([
            'question_id' => $questionId,
            'player_id' => $player->id,
            'quiz_id' => $quiz->id,
            'score' => $score,
            'answered' => $answered
        ]);
```

The variable $answered gets a value, I have tested that in the console, when I was testing it with:

```
return ['answered' => $answered]
```

And I was getting the correct values there, but nothing was written in the DB. Not sure why is that happening?

Comment: Have you added the column to the `$fillable` attribute in the model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `answered` in the `$fillable` array, because `create` method uses [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment).